# Calculating distance between points in matlab

Tags: matlab, k-means, euclidean-distance

Having difficulty understanding the following code in Matlab to calculate Euclidean distance between two points, where X is the data to be classified and label corresponds to cluster membership.

```
label = ones(1, data_dim);
[N,~]=size(X);
[c,~]=size(clusters);
dist = zeros(N,c);
for i = 1:c
    dist(:,i) = sum(bsxfun(@minus, X, clusters(i,:)).^2, 2);
end

[~,label] = min(dist,[],2);
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here and maybe explain it from first principles without using `bsxfun`?

Answer (score 1):

- The `for` loop iterates over every row in `clusters`. Each row is presumably the coordinates of a point in that cluster.
- `bsxfun(@minus, X, clusters(i,:)` subtracts that particular cluster row from every row in X. In other words, it outputs a matrix where the first row is `X(1,:) - clusters(i,:)`, the second row is `X(2,:) - clusters(i,:)`, etc. This is like a direction vector from each point in `X` to the particular cluster point `i`.
- Every value is squared (`.^2`) and then these are summed along each row (`sum(...,2)`) . That gives you a column vector containing the square of the Euclidean distance from every point in `X` to the cluster point. This is stored in the matrix 'dist' which therefore contains the square of the distance from every point in X to each point in `clusters`
- the `min(dist,[],2)` command finds the minimum of these values over each column of `dist`, i.e. it find the minimum distance for each point in `x`. However, the actual value is ignored and instead the index is stored in `label` - this index corresponds to the cluster which had the minimum distance